# resize with different parameters for specific folder from storage [storage-resize-images extension]

Tags: firebase, firebase-extensions

I want to have differents config paramaters for specific folders for avoid extra billing for make unnecessary resizes but dunno if the extension support it.

I have 2 folders, :

/profile --> I want 40x40 and 180x180

/Images --> I want 200x300, etc.

Is there a way to achieve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you consider adding the extension to your project twice, and configuring different output folders?

Comment: Cross-posted on [Github](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/issues/173)

Comment: I did now thanks !